# What is the "correct" way of handling Window instances in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

While creating WPF applications and working with Window class I created my own pattern of handling Window instances. In case I need only one instance of Window my approach is:

```
private CustomWindow CustomWindow;
private void MenuItemCustomWindowOpenClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomWindow == null)
        {
            CustomWindow = new CustomWindow();
            CustomWindow.Closed += delegate
            {
                CustomWindow = null;
            };
            CustomWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

CustomWindow is a class that inherits Window class.

I wanted to know if there is a better way? What should I use if I wanted to keep instance and not create new one? Can I reuse already closed window?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the instance? Is it that you are populating the `window` dynamically ? If so, firstly, i don't think the dynamic approach is a good one(unless it's written very proficiently). Last but not the least, if you want to keep the instance, then keep it, don't pass a null reference to it.

Comment: I want to keep instance in case I have data on it, for example, when first creating instance I could load up some variables and later I wouldn't need to do that

Comment: Then keep the instance, don't pass a null reference to it.

Comment: If window is closed and i try to Show() it again i get 'Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.'
That's why I asked if I can reuse already closed window

Comment: If you need a single instance throughout the lifetime of your application you can use `Window.Hide()`. If you need to close the Window, you'll have to recreate it next time, as the error message indicates.

Comment: When the window is 'closed', it means it is getting `disposed`. What you might wanna do is not close the window, instead hide it and then show it when required.

Comment: So I suppose I would need to override Close event and call Hide instead?

If so, my current options are:
Pass important variables between window instances, Close event functions normally.
Always have one instance of window, override Close event to hide window instead, window is never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirements state that you need to re-use your Windows for some reason, my suggestion is to do not do it. Your could will be much more clean and readable.

In case you need to do so, my 2 cents are to implements a sort of `IWindowsManager` to inject be injected to any class who needs to use `Windows`.

Is could be a good starting point.

**IWindowsManager**

```
interface IWindowsManager : IDisposable
{
    Window GetWindow<T>() where T : Window;

    void ShowWindow<T>() where T : Window;

    void CloseWindow<T>() where T : Window;
}
```

**WindowsManager**

```
class WindowsManager : IWindowsManager
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Window> windows;
    private bool disposed;

    public WindowsManager()
    {
        this.windows = new Dictionary<Type, Window>();
        this.disposed = false;
    }

    public Window GetWindow<T>() where T : Window
    {
        if (this.windows.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            return this.windows[typeof(T)];

        var w = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as Window;
        if (w == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException($"The passed Type {typeof(T)} does not extend Window class.");
        w.Closing += W_Closing;

        this.windows.Add(typeof(T), w);
        return w;
    }

    private void W_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Window w = sender as Window;
        w.Hide();
    }

    public void ShowWindow<T>() where T : Window
    {
        Window w = null;

        if (!this.windows.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            w = this.GetWindow<T>();

        w = this.windows[typeof(T)];

        w.Show();
    }

    public void CloseWindow<T>() where T : Window
    {
        if (!this.windows.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException($"Failed to get existing Window of Type {typeof(T)}");

        var w = this.windows[typeof(T)];

        w.Hide();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (var window in this.windows)
                {
                    var w = window.Value;
                    w.Close();
                    w.Closing -= W_Closing;
                }
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`WindowsManager` implements `IDisposable` interface to close windows when disposed. Any other logic might be implemented based on your requirements.

To let the code work properly you have to use the `WindowsManager` instance when showing or closing `Window` and do not call `WindowXXX.Show()` or `WindowXXX.Close()` directly.

Comment: How about when I press X in the window?

Comment: Edited my post by adding handling of X button pressed

Answer (score 0):

That seems fine. To re-use the window, you have to handle the `Closing` event and cancel it, then `Hide` the window instead of closing it. To open it up again you can call `Show` again.

Comment: Is there another way without canceling event? I might want to actually close the window at some point. Of course I can work around that, just wanted to know another way

Comment: Not that i know of. If you need a way to close it you can just add a boolean flag and then add an if clause to only cancel if that flag is set or unset.